# C# Error Using ProtectedData.Unprotect() Function

Tags: c#, encryption, wincrypt

I'm experimenting with `ProtectData.Protect()` and `ProtectData.Unprotect()` functions in C#. I've written a program that writes encrypted data to an SQLite database, and then reads the database and decrypt the data. Every time I run my code I receive the following error:

```
   Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
   at MyProgram.ReadData(SQLiteConnection conn)
   at MyProgram.Main()
```

The full code is very long, but here is the `decrypt()` function. I'm passing a byte array; I have verified the type to be a byte array using `myByteData.GetType()`, which returns `System.Byte[]`.

```
public static byte [] decrypt( byte [] data ) {
        
        byte [] s_additionalEntropy = null;
        
        try {
            
            //Decrypt
            return ProtectedData.Unprotect( data, s_additionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser );
            
        }catch{
            
            try {
            
                return ProtectedData.Unprotect( data, s_additionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine );
                
            }catch (Exception e){
                
                Console.Write("Error: ");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the example here is straightforward: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.dataprotectionscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: As a general comment, I wouldn't use these functions to encrypt/decrypt data. being tied to a current user key or a machine key is liable to bite you.